# Regex search and replace - reformatting name

Tags: regex, search, replace, contacts, samsung-mobile

I have all the mobile phone contacts from a Samsung A411 in one large file, to be imported into a Samsung Galaxy S3 phone/contacts.

There is just one field that I can't do a standard 'replace' with, using Kate. Here is what I need to do:

N:Mickey Mouse

to be replaced with ..

N:Mouse;Mickey;;;

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -r 's/N:(\w*) (\w*)/N:\2;\1;;;/g' file.txt
```

Explanation of the [s command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html) used:

```
s/
   N:      # literal string "N:"          ┐
   (       # begin of capture group       │
      \w   # any word character           │
        *  # ...repeated 0 or more times  ├ regex
   )       # end of capture group         │
           # literal " " (space)          │
   (\w*)   # same capture group as above  ┘
/
   N:      # literal string "N:"          ┐
   \2      # backreference to 2nd group   │
   ;       # literal ";"                  ├ replacement
   \1      # backreference to 1st group   │
   ;;;     # literal ";;;"                ┘
/
   g       # apply to all matches         ] flags
```

I used `sed -r` (extended regular expressions) in order to avoid escaping each bracket in the command for the sake of readability.

Comment: Thanks, that nearly worked. Here is what happened  input

N:Mickey Mouse  
FN:Mickey Mouse  

output

N:Mouse;Mickey;;;  
N:Mouse;Mickey;;;  
FN:Mouse;Mickey;;;  
FN:Mouse;Mickey;;;

Comment: So, the "N:" record was replaced correctly, but it was added in again. The "FN:" record should not be replaced at all, or added to.

Comment: Decided to use the output from the "sed" above, and then manually edit the file. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: I fixed the command in order to avoid that. If this provides a solution to your problem, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @YassinHajaj I've added an explanation in the answer.

Comment: @etuardu Thank you :)

Comment: @etuardu - The "N" record is fine now, and there is no "N" duplicate. However, the "FN" line has been replaced. The "FN" should not be modified at all.

Answer (score 0):

> The "N" record is fine now, and there is no "N" duplicate. However,
>   the "FN" line has been replaced. The "FN" should not be modified at
>   all.

To replace only lines that start with `N:`, insert a `^` (*match the beginning of the line*), i. e.

```
sed -r 's/^N:…
```